# conversion for explicit argument in template

Tags: c++, templates

From C++ Primer, I know that for template's parameter arguments, only two kinds of conversions are performed: one is **const conversion**, another one is **array/function to pointer conversion**.

However, when it comes to explicit argument, it seems that everything changes.
Assume we have a template function:

```
template <typename T>
int compare(const T &a, const T &b)
{
    // do comparison
}
```

If no explicit argument involved, function call like this is illegal:

```
compare("foo", "foobar");
```

The weird thing happens (actually, it might not be weird but I do not understand) when we explicitly do:

```
compare<std::string>("foo", "foobar");
```

It seems that in the second call, **"foo"** and **"foobar"** are converted to `std::string`, which is controversial.

Is there any special rules for template explicit arguments? Thanks.

Comment: Why does this seem controversial to you? By providing the explicit template parameter you are indicating you would like to cast the corresponding `T` arguments to a `const std::string&`, which it does via a `std::string` constructor overload using your character string literals. What behavior were you expecting? If the `T` has no casting constructor (or has an `explicit` one) then this will not happen.

Comment: Does it mean that when we explicit bind the T with std::string, the actual function code is generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case the compiler tries to deduce the type `T` from the given parameters. From the first parameter the compiler deduces the type `const char (&)[4]` (aka. reference to an array of 4 characters), from the second it gets `const char (&)[7]`. The two types don't match and the compiler can't figure out what `T` should be.

In the second example you explicitly specify that the `T` template parameter should be  `std::string`. So `T` *will* be `std::string`. The compiler accepts the type you give and checks if the given function parameters match that type. In this case the parameters fit, because `"foo"` and `"foobar"` can be implicitly converted to `std::string`. (The `const char[]` degrade to `const char*`, and then there is a constructor that can construct a `std::string` from a `const char*`)

Comment: +1: It is important to stress that for template argument deduction, types must be perfect matches (i.e. it will not allow conversions). Also, if the arguments were of type `T` rather than `T const &`, then the arrays will decay into pointers and that would also work.